# Android HTTP POST EXECUTE METHOD

Tags: android, http-post

I am executing http post from url. But not able to execute the response from http post.

Below is my code:

```
try {
    htttpget = new HttpGet(myurl);
    System.out.println("check2");

    response1 = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);     
    System.out.println("check3");
    System.out.println("responsegettingvalues" + response1);
    checkingresponse(response1,2);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("catch"+e.getMessage());
}
```

and here is my logcat:

> 01-28 17:01:13.231: E/AndroidRuntime(20257):  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
>   01-28 17:01:13.231: E/AndroidRuntime(20257):    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.isStale(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:205)
>   01-28 17:01:13.231: E/AndroidRuntime(20257):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.isStale(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:185)
>   01-28 17:01:13.231: E/AndroidRuntime(20257):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:336)
>   01-28 17:01:13.231: E/AndroidRuntime(20257):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

Comment: you are calling httpget not post  htttpget = new HttpGet(myurl) see your code

Comment: Tried using HttpPost. But no output

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code

```
try {
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = this.httpClient.execute(postMethod);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            value = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("exception is", "" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   private void framePost() {
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            List<NameValuePair> mPairs = getNameValuePairs();
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(mPairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){
                Log.i("TAG", "Success");
            }
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            Log.i("TAG", "Error");
        }

    }



private List<NameValuePair> getNameValuePairs() {
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> pair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value));
            return pair;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("TAG", "error");
        }
    }
```